# The Sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ Does Not Converge in $\mathbb{R}$ w. discrete metric

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

> Show that, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric, the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge.

I'd appreciate a proof verification/help. This is how I started my proof:

Our sequence $S := (\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is $1, \frac{1}{2}, ... , \frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Since none of the terms in $S$ are equal, i.e. $s_i \ne s_j$ for $i \ne j$, with the discrete metric the distance between all the terms of $S$ is $1$. (Since wrt. discrete metric, $d(x, y) = 1$ if $x \ne y$). This means the distance between all our terms is $1$. **This means that $s_n$ is not getting arbitrarily getting close to any term. So, $S$ cannot converge.**

I can't really put the bolded part of the proof into "mathematical language." Should I have started this with proof by contradiction? I'd appreciate any correction/guidance in proving the statement. Thank you.

Comment: You're showing it does not converge by showing it is not Cauchy. You just have to check that all convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences, and you're done.

Comment: @JPLK actually I don't think that is possible. $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with discrete metric is not a complete space, thus it shouldn't be, in general, true that all Cauchy sequences converge in the space.

Comment: Go back to the definition of limit. Suppose it converged to $L$, What $\delta$ could you find for $\epsilon = 1/3$? In fact why not prove a stronger theorem: in a discrete metric space a sequence converges if and only if it's eventually constant?

Comment: @Defcon97 You misread my comment. Somebody else did not misread my comment and posted it as an answer. And BTW (though it does not play a role here) the discrete real line IS a complete space, notice the only cauchy sequences there are eventually constant sequences, and they do converge.

Comment: @EthanBolker beat me to it! Sometimes the easiest proof is to prove a more general claim.

Comment: @JPLK ...you are right i didn't think about it, nice answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(s_n)$ would converge. Then it is a Cauchy sequence (convergence always implies Cauchy). However, as you pointed out, it is **not** Cauchy, which contradicts the convergence assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the sequence converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, any open set containing $x$ must contain all but finitely many terms of the sequence (definition of limit in a topological space). Consider the open set $\{x\}$. Obviously, this contains $x$. Then, all but finitely many terms of the sequence are in the set $\{x\}$. But, this means all but finitely many terms of the sequence are equal to $x$ and yet at the same time, $\frac{1}{n}\neq \frac{1}{m}$ for $m\neq n$ so we have a contradiction.